# A program that gives the longest time (In minutes) a person spends in the bank

Tags: c++

**Input:**
The first line of the standard input contains the count of events (1≤N≤100) and a
time (1≤X≤23). The next N lines contain the data of events: in the form of 4 integers separated
by a space. The first number is the hour part of the time of the event (0≤H≤23), the
second is the minute part of the time (0≤M≤59). The third number is 1, if the event is an entry,
-1, if it is an exit, -2 if it is a dispense, and 2 if it is a deposit. The fourth number is a
positive integer (1≤S≤10 000 000), either the card ID or the amount (depending on the
the previous parameter).

**Output:**
The first line of the standard output should contain the longest time (in minutes)
the customer was in the bank.

**Example Input**

```
7            
11 10 1 12345
11 50 -2 10000
12 10 -1 12345
23 10 1 24680
23 11 -2 5000
23 15 1 13579
23 20 1 98765
```

**Expected Output**

```
60
```

**Code**

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <climits>
    using namespace std;
    
    int main() {
      int row;
      cin >> row;
      const int col = 4;
      int longestInbank = 0;
      int time[row][col];
      for (int i = 0; i < row; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++){
            cin >> time[i][j];
        }
      }
      int libMinutes = 0;
      for ( int i = 1; i <= row; i++){
      if (time[i][3] == time[i+1][3]){
        longestInbank = time[i+1][0] - time[i][0];
        }
        libMinutes = longestInbank * 60;
      }
      cout << libMinutes << "";
    }
```

Comment: OK, so what is the question?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Take a look a how to make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What have you tried so far, and what error are you getting? This is a not a "do your homework for you" site.

Comment: I want to upload my code so that you can review but I'm struggling

Comment: We need to see your attempted code and where you're running into an issue. Otherwise, we cannot help you.

Comment: `int time[row][col];` is a variable-length array and not allowed in standard C++. You should replace it with `std::vector<std::vector<int>> time(row, std::vector(col))`. `time[i+1][3]` goes out of bounds for `i == row` and `i == row - 1`.

Comment: I just managed to upload it, I'm new here so I was still understanding how the question system works, can you see it now?

Comment: It's unclear for me how `if (time[i][3] == time[i+1][3]){` is related to this task? Can you describe your algorithm? You have to find lines like `11 10 1 12345` and the corresponding line like `12 10 -1 12345`. Where exactly does this happen in your code? Where do you calculate the time between these events?

Comment: @ThomasSablik my algorithm compares ID numbers of people who actually went into the bank and came out, ID 12345 by far seems to be the only one but I failed to increment the difference between the time which should be (12 - 11) from the first elements which are the actual count I want

Comment: In your algorithm you only consider consecutive events but in the example `11 10 1 12345` and `12 10 -1 12345` are not consecutive events.

Comment: @ThomasSablik yes this is where I hit a brick and I was hoping someone can explain to me how to compare non-consecutive events

Comment: You need to loop over the following events and find the exit event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a possible implementation of finding the longest time a customer has spent in the bank.

```cpp
int max_time = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= row; ++i) {
  // find entry event
  if (time[i][2] == 1) {
    // loop over following events
    for (int j = i; j < row; ++j) {
      // find fitting exit event
      if (time[j][3] == time[i][3] && time[j][2] == -1) {
        int duration = (time[j][0] - time[i][0]) * 60 + time[j][1] - time[i][1];
        if (duration > max_time) {
          max_time = duration;
        }
        break; // break out of inner loop after finding exit
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much this solved the non-consecutive issue I was having

Comment: @KatzTrill then consider accepting this answer as your solution.